Formattingalo: MORE formatting in Chat.SE!




Screenshot / Code Snippet

About
This userscript allows you to underline your text, change the color, and even the size!
Formatting guide



Format
Syntax
Non-text parameters
Notes




Underline
^^^text^^^
None
None.


Color
###ffffff text###
ffffff represents color
Only supports colors in 6-digit hex notation.


Size
...10 text...
10 represents size
Size restricted to 99px to prevent abuse. Does not support negative values.



License
It is licensed under the GNU Affero General Public License v3.0.
Download
https://github.com/PlaceReporter99/Userscripts/blob/main/formattingalo.js
Platform
Tested on Tampermonkey on Google Chrome.
Contact
I created this app. You can send a message here, create an issue on the GitHub repository, or post an answer to this question.
Code
The code is here, it uses Tampermonkey JavaScript.
